# How can i control call popup options in IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Here is my situation, i have a contact list in my Ionic 5 App which can include one or more phone numbers per contact. Some of them might be mobile nd support SMS as well. so for now when I create the phone array in my list I use the below code to allow the user to initiate a call

```
  <p *ngIf="phone.type === 'Mobile'">
    <ion-icon class="big center green" ios="car"></ion-icon> 
    <a (click)="dialNumber(phone.number)">({{phone.number | slice:0:3 }})
            {{phone.number | slice:3:6 }}-{{phone.number | slice:6:10 }}
    </a>
  </p>

dialNumber(nbr: string) {
    this.callNumber.callNumber(nbr, true)
  .then(res => console.log('Launched dialer!', res))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error launching dialer', err));
  }
```

The Above Code creates a popup at the lower part of screen with the option of Call that number and Cancel. What i would like to actually do is show all the Numbers of the contact so user can click on the desired nbr. also i would like to be able to have items in popup that will trigger an SMS vs a call.
So my question is how would i go to control the popup and add additional nbrs and possibly allow for SMS.

This is a screenshot what it looks like currently

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're using [this Cordova plugin](https://github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin) so you can't change the options shown in that popup.

What you can do is to **show your own custom action sheet** when the user clicks on the contact, and then set the available options based on the contact that has been selected.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/action-sheet

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActionSheetController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'action-sheet-example',
  templateUrl: 'action-sheet-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./action-sheet-example.css'],
})
export class ActionSheetExample {

  constructor(public actionSheetController: ActionSheetController) {}

  async presentActionSheet() {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
      header: 'Albums',
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          role: 'destructive',
          icon: 'trash',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Delete clicked');
          }
        }, 
        {
          text: 'Share',
          icon: 'share',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Share clicked');
          }
        }, 
        {
          text: 'Play (open modal)',
          icon: 'caret-forward-circle',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Play clicked');
          }
        }, 
        {
          text: 'Favorite',
          icon: 'heart',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Favorite clicked');
          }
        }, 
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          icon: 'close',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    
    await actionSheet.present();
  }

}
```

So in that case, when the user clicks on a contact that user would see your action sheet with options to send an SMS and to make a call, and if the user selects to make a call you'd hide the action sheet and then you'd call the Cordova plugin.

Comment: Thanks that should work, but i am wondering is there a way to hide or suppress the cordova call action sheet ? its not that great if user clicks call number on my custom sheet and then has to press call again on the plugin. Also would this change if i use capacitor vs cordova ?

Comment: @ConfusedCoder I don't really know the details of that Cordova plugin specifically but I imagine that the underlying OS will always ask the user if he/she really wants to make the phone call so I guess it won't be possible to skip that step :(